# Calling a function in another file using its name

Tags: python

What is the best way to go about calling a function in Python?
I need to get the return value of the function
This is the function I want to call in another file in the same folder

[image]

Comment: You can import the file without the ```py``` extension, then call the ```pullData```

Answer (score 1):

You can import your function(s) and find it in `globals()` dictionary:

```
from your_module import pullData, other_function1, other_function2

function_name = 'pullData'
function = globals()[function_name]

returned_value = function(price, allprice)
```

another way is to import the module and get the function from its attributes:

```
import your_module

function_name = 'pullData'
function = getattr(your_module, function_name)

returned_value = function(price, allprice)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from <file_name> import pullData
```

Where `file_name` is the file that exposts the function `pullData`